# How to vertically center a content spanning multiple rows without using nested tables?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

**I don't want to use nested tables.** My current code produces the following result.

[image]

And I want to get the following output.

[image]

And the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,longtable}

\parindent=0pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt\relax
\tabcolsep=5pt\relax

\newcolumntype{A}[2]{%
    >{\minipage{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#2\arrayrulewidth\relax}\vspace\tabcolsep}%
    c<{\vspace\tabcolsep\endminipage}}


\newcommand\x{\centering$\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(x)+C$}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{
            |A{0.2}{1.5}    % 0.2 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
            |A{0.5}{1}      % 0.5 of \linewidth, 1 of \arrayrulewidth
            |A{0.3}{1.5}    % 0.3 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
            |}\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FIRST ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\x & \multicolumn{2}{
                A{0.8}{1.5} % 0.8 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
                |}{\x} \tabularnewline\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SECOND ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{
        |A{0.7}{1.5}    % 0.7 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
        |}{\multirow{2}{*}{\x}} &
                                                        \x \tabularnewline\cline{3-3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THIRD ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{
        |A{0.7}{1.5}    % 0.7 of \linewdith, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
        |}{}                    & 
                                                        \x \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How to vertically center a content spanning multiple rows without using nested tables?

---

I have tried all answers (excluding Aditya's answer) and all don't vertically center the cell spanning multiple rows. Please kindly recheck your answer, or I might be wrong. :-)

Comment: A post bounty of 500 will be given for an accepted answer. The post bounty is one that will be presented after executing a green check mark. If no useful answer, then there will be no such a bounty. :-)

Comment: If you actually start the bounty, you will get the added benefit of your question being advertised more prominently on the site. And for people willing to work on an answer, it gives the added benefit of knowing that there will actually be at least some points awarded, if necessary by community verdict.

Comment: @Jake: It may waste the bounty if no useful answer exists.

Comment: In that case, the bounty rep was the cost of drawing attention.

Comment: A bounty of 50 is enough to draw attention. But I will do it 10 times.

Comment: As far as I can see, all provided solutions center the cell content correctly. It would probably help if you would tell each answerer individually what shortcoming you see in their answer.

Comment: @JAKE: I will show the shortcoming next week. I have many tasks to be done in this week. Sorry!

Comment: @xport: Maybe you should explain more clearly what you mean by "I have tried all answers ... and all don't vertically center the cell spanning multiple rows". I had understood your positioning instructions as follows: to have the same vertical distance between the top (bottom) of the integral sign and the rule above (below) the sign. Did you want us to center the baseline of the math formula inside the box instead? Please advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the package `ltablex`is available on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex
Three X columns must give 3X when you want to have different columns widths: 0.6+1.5+0.9=3
For the 2nd and 3rd row you have 2X+1X=3X

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut,ltablex,calc}
\parindent=0pt
\tabcolsep=5pt
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rule{0pt}{\tabcolsep}\newline}
                      X
                     <{\newline\rule[-\tabcolsep]{0pt}{\tabcolsep}}}

\newcommand\x{\makebox[\hsize]{$\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(x)+C$}}

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| A{0.6} | A{1.5} | A{0.9} |}\hline
\x & \multicolumn{2}{A{2.4}|}{\x} \tabularnewline\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SECOND ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{|A{2}|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\x}} &  \x\tabularnewline\cline{3-3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THIRD ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{|A{2}|}{}                       &  \x \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Next bounty of 450 will automatically be yours. Thanks.

Comment: @xport: Just to make sure the substantial amount of reputation isn't lost: The bounty will not be assigned automatically, and not even the half-bounty that can be assigned automatically will work in this case, since it's not a new answer. You will have to assign the bounty manually. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/what-happened-to-the-bounty

Answer (score 5):

You could obtain the desired result with a simple modification to your original code, replacing `\multirow{2}{*}{\x}` with `\hfil\multirow{4}{*}{\x}\hfil` in the second row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,longtable}

\parindent=0pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt\relax
\tabcolsep=5pt\relax

\newcolumntype{A}[2]{%
    >{\minipage{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#2\arrayrulewidth\relax}\vspace\tabcolsep}%
    c<{\vspace\tabcolsep\endminipage}}


\newcommand\x{\centering$\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(x)+C$}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{
            |A{0.2}{1.5}    % 0.2 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
            |A{0.5}{1}      % 0.5 of \linewidth, 1 of \arrayrulewidth
            |A{0.3}{1.5}    % 0.3 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
            |}\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FIRST ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\x & \multicolumn{2}{
                A{0.8}{1.5} % 0.8 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
                |}{\x} \tabularnewline\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SECOND ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{
        |A{0.7}{1.5}    % 0.7 of \linewidth, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
        |}{\hfil\multirow{4}{*}{\x}\hfil} & \x \tabularnewline\cline{3-3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THIRD ROW %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\multicolumn{2}{
        |A{0.7}{1.5}    % 0.7 of \linewdith, 1.5 of \arrayrulewidth
        |}{}  & \x \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My proposed solution dispenses with `minipages` and explicit `\vspace` instructions. This is achieved by inserting a "strut" automatically in each row; the height of the strut exceeds that of the math expressions by a certain amount.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx}

\parindent=0pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\tabcolsep=5pt

%% 'rbstrut' is short for 'really big strut'
\newcommand{\rbstrut}{\ensuremath{\vphantom{\displaystyle \int\limits_a^t}}}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize \centering \arraybackslash\rbstrut}X}

\newcommand\x{\ensuremath{\displaystyle\int f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(x)+C}}

\begin{document}

%% in tabularx terminology, the sum of the widths (arguments of A) have to
%% add up to the integer (in this case 3) that equals the number of columsn
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| A{0.6} | A{1.5} | A{0.9} |}
\hline
%%%% FIRST ROW 
\x & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\x} \\    \hline
%%%% SECOND ROW 
\multicolumn{2}{|A{2.1}|}{ \multirow{4}{*}{\x} } & \x \\    \cline{3-3}
%%%% THIRD ROW
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  &  \x \\    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For typesetting such tables, I find that the interface provided by ConTeXt is much easier to read.

```
\startsetups table:setup
  \setupTABLE[each][each][align={middle,middle}, frame=on, framecolor=red]
  \setupTABLE[column][1] [width=0.2\hsize]
  \setupTABLE[column][2] [width=0.5\hsize]
  \setupTABLE[column][3] [width=0.3\hsize]
\stopsetups

\startbuffer
$\displaystyle \int f(x)\,\normal{d}x=F(x)+C$
\stopbuffer

\starttext

  \bTABLE[setups=table:setup]
    \bTR
      \bTD \getbuffer \eTD \bTD[nc=2] \getbuffer \eTD 
    \eTR
    \bTR
      \bTD[nc=2, nr=2] \getbuffer \eTD \bTD \getbuffer \eTD 
    \eTR
    \bTR
       \bTD \getbuffer \eTD 
    \eTR
  \eTABLE
\stoptext
```

This gives

[image]